# Easiest way to render HTML from String in Java

Tags: java, swing

I need to render HTML page from a Java String. The String contains a full HTML  page which may include CSS and Javascript. I know that some CSS/script reference may missing because I only has the html, so it's not a problem.

I have tried using JEditorPane, but it only works for very simple HTML. If it can't render, it will display nothing.
Is there any library I can use?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Desktop` class. It will open the default browser of your platform.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate With the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more information and working examples.